# How to compare two SOAP responses in SoapUI for discrepancies, using Groovy script or something else

Tags: soap, groovy, automation, comparison, soapui

I would like to compare for discrepancies(namespaces, content) two SOAP responses in SoapUI that i get at the same time, and display the differences in the SoapUI log or log.info, currently i got only a piece of code to get the response and put it in a variable:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) ;
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetAttachementList#Response" ) ;
log.info(holder.getXml());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use soapui assertions.

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/getting-started-with-assertions.html